# How do the aliens use the Earth molten core to grow their technology?

Tags: independence-day, independence-day-resurgence

The big sphere alien ship said that the Bad Guy aliens were trying to suck out Earth's molten core, to refuel their ship and "**grow their technology**".

I get how you can hand-wave using it to refuel.

But how can sucking out Earth's liquid core "**grow their technology**"?

<sub>*I'm only looking for in-universe answers, preferably based in canon (the only rational explanation I myself can come up with is, **you need more energy to upgrade your tech, not just better designs/science/engineering to come up with the upgrade ideas***)</sub>

Comment: Does he say "upgrade"? I thought he said "grow"...

Comment: @Valorum - are you **seriously** gonna make me re-watch that *ahem* amazing work of art again just to confirm wording? That's Sith-grade evil.

Comment: @Valorum - yep, it was "grow". Edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual mechanism by which new ships are "grown" remains a mystery, but apparently it involves sucking up the [liquid hot magma](https://media.giphy.com/media/xT0Gqs2LQIevTVmjNm/giphy.gif) and turning it into baby motherships that can then be sent off to find new planetary systems to conquer.

> *“Correct,” it said. “A harvester ship conquered our planet and sucked
> out its molten core.” As it spoke it projected a hologram to
> illustrate. The massive vessel latched onto the planet and began to
> grow the same kinds of vine-like structures that were now enveloping
> the east coast of the United States. “They use planetary cores to
> refuel their ships and grow their technology. They have done this to
> thousands of species. They are Armageddon. The end of everything.” **The
> hologram showed a smaller ship budding from the hull of the harvester,
> and detaching. It was an exact copy of the mother ship they had
> destroyed during the War of ’96.***
>
> *So that was just a baby, David thought. One of probably thousands sent
> out into the universe to find the next feeding ground. He’d seen the
> growth of their technology on the level of individual organisms, but
> it was another thing to observe it at such a massive scale. The
> combination of biotechnology and advanced materials science was both
> intoxicating—because of the possibilities—and terrifying, because of
> the race that possessed it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Independence Day: Resurgence - A Novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(book_series)#Independence_Day:_Resurgence)</sup></sub>