# Why do the aliens need molten core from Earth, specifically?

Tags: independence-day, independence-day-resurgence

The big sphere alien ship said that the Bad Guy aliens were trying to suck out Earth's molten core, to refuel their ship (and [upgrade their technology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145817/how-do-the-aliens-use-the-earth-liquid-core-to-upgrade-their-technology), to boot).

Why did the aliens need to risk damage (never mind defeat) coming to Earth, when they could have easily gotten the molten core from any other Earth-like planet without a civilization on it, of which there are tons.

Comment: its actually an interesting question how many planets exist that still have a molten core; my impression was actually that it's relatively uncommon...

Comment: @KutuluMike - Good point and good question. Is there Astronomy.SE? I suspect Space.SE would consider that off-topic.

Comment: [yes there is](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/), and in fact: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/12903/do-all-planets-have-a-molten-core is a good start. Also note that, of the planets we can "detect", most of the are gas giants (because bigger == easier to see) and they tend to have solid cores.

Comment: @KutuluMike - Good find! Best as I can figure from those answers, the actual answer is "we don't really know how many at this point".

Comment: that's what I understand to be true... we're just starting to get good at finding Earth-sized planets so our understanding of their life cycle is just getting started.

Comment: I suppose it served a two-fold purpose: eliminate the newly found threat, and get some nice gooey molten core whilst they're at it.

Comment: I guess someone else saw CinemaSins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implication seems to be that they do this to *every* planet with a molten core that they encounter. It could be surmised that their interest in Earth was especially piqued by our active (and easily accessible) lava core, as opposed to other rocky planets in the Solar System such as Mars, Venus and Mercury whose cores are [largely solidified.](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Earth-have-an-active-core-while-Venus-and-Mars-do-not)

> *So that was just a baby, David thought. **One of probably thousands sent
> out into the universe to find the next feeding ground.** He’d seen the
> growth of their technology on the level of individual organisms, but
> it was another thing to observe it at such a massive scale. The
> combination of biotechnology and advanced materials science was both
> intoxicating—because of the possibilities—and terrifying, because of
> the race that possessed it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Independence Day: Resurgence - Novelisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(book_series)#Independence_Day:_Resurgence)</sup></sub>